Migrate Markdown files to Content type
I am working on a migrating Markdown files from a repo into my Drupal site and not sure if this is possible. I have created a new content type that is just the title field and the body that accepts Full HTML. The Markdown files would basically be the node on the site and anytime a new file is created or an old one is updated, it would update that node or create a new one after a Cron job is run.
How could I create this kind of migration in Drupal?

Providing tutorials for building complex features is beyond the scope of this site I'm afraid (and something like this would definitely be a complex, multi-step implementation). I think the best advice would be to break this down into its smallest parts, and approach each separately. Finding/implementing a Markdown migrate source would be one, setting up a system to re-run migrations from files when they change (or some other trigger like CI/CD) would be another, and so on. Then the final job would be gluing those together.

You can set up a text format using Markdown, and import the text into that.

Install the markdown module: composer require league/commonmark ^1.0; composer require drupal/markdown; drush en markdown
Create a text format named Markdown at Admin -> Configuration -> Content Authoring -> Text Formats and Editors -> Add Text Format
Ensure that the Markdown filter is checked/enabled for the Text Format
Create a field of type text formatted on some entity
Migrate the content into the field created in step 4, setting the text format to markdown (assuming you named your Text format 'Markdown').

